# CKEditor 4 Widget with Draggable contents

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to make a CKEditor widget with children that listen to the `dragstart` `drag` and `dragend` events. The issue is that these events never get fired - it's like the `.cke_widget_wrapper` (the div that wraps widgets) cancels those events.

Note that I'm not trying to make the entire widget draggable (part of the widget functionality), but make elements within the widget draggable.

If I unwrap the children of `.cke_widget_wrapper` (thereby removing the wrapper) then everything works as expected. But it seems this wrapper stops children from dragging.

I won't post the code on how I'm doing the dragging because it works as expected in an isolated test case, and as explained, works when I unwrap the widget from `.cke_widget_wrapper`.

Here's how I'm creating the widget:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('embed', {
    init: function(editor) {
        editor.widgets.add('gallery', {
            init: function() {
                // code here that generates the HTML
            },
            upcast: function(element) {
                // Defines which elements will become widgets.
                if (element.hasClass('gallery')) {
                    return true;
                }
            },
            downcast: function(element) {
                element.setHtml("");
            },
            draggable: false, // This does not make a difference, but I set it to false because I don't want to use the built in widget dragging functionality
            template: "<div class="gallery" trix-id='{id}'></div>",
            defaults: function() {
                return {id: 1} // As an example
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here's the generated HTML:

```
<div tabindex="-1" contenteditable="false" data-cke-widget-wrapper="1" data-cke-filter="off" class="cke_widget_wrapper cke_widget_block cke_widget_selected" data-cke-display-name="gallery" data-cke-widget-id="0">
    <div class="gallery cke_widget_element" trix-id="1" data-cke-widget-upcasted="1" data-cke-widget-keep-attr="0" data-widget="gallery">
        <!-- Other HTML -->
        <div class="resize" draggable="true" trix-gallery-resize="1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `div.resize` element has event handlers attached to it to allow dragging. As mentioned, this works in an isolated test case, and when I remove the `.cke_widget_wrapper` wrapper.

Does anyone know how I can allow dragging within the widget, so that the event handlers behave normally on the `.resize` element?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As usual, as soon as I post a question to SO I work out the answer.

CKEditor attaches a `mousedown` event to the editable area which does many things, but it seems one of the side effects is it stops widget contents from being draggable.

All I had to do was attach an `mousedown` event handler to the `.resize` element which calls `event.stopPropagation`, like so:

```
element.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Easy!

Comment: i have a plugin that appends html5 video tag, how can i get an advantage of your experience here.